# ElementRef is undefined in TemplateRef

Tags: angular

Experimenting with ElementRef, TemplateRef, ViewRef and ViewContainerRef in Angular. I have created an HTML template, from there I want to create a View and pass that view to ViewContainerRef but it isn't working

Code for template

```
template: `
  <ng-container #vc></ng-container>
  <ng-template #mytmpl>
    <div>Name: <input type="text" name="name" /> </div>
    <div>Gender: 
      <select  name="gender" >
        <option>Male(1)</option>
        <option>Female(2)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>About you: <textarea ></textarea></div>
    <div>Married: <input type="checkbox" /></div>      
    <div>Children:     
      <ng-container *ngFor = "let option of this.selectOptions">
        <input  type="radio" [id]="option" name="children" [value]=option [(ngModel)]="this.children"/> {{option}}
      </ng-container>
   </div>
   <p>Some para</p>
   <p>Para with span <span>Inside span</span></p>
  </ng-template>
`
```

In the class, I access the template and view container

```
@ViewChild('vc',{read:ViewContainerRef}) v:ViewContainerRef;
@ViewChildren("mytmpl") myTemplateList:TemplateRef<any>;
```

I use the following code to create the view

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  let elementRef = this.myTemplateList.elementRef
  let view = this.myTemplateList.createEmbeddedView(null)
  this.v.insert(view)
  console.log(elementRef);
}
```

**Problems**

1) elementRef is undefined!- I want to print on the console, all the elements inside the template. but elementRef is undefined!

2) I get the error that createEmbeddedView is not a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I get the error that createEmbeddedView is not a function.

There are few problems:

1) Use `{read: TemplateRef}` here:

```
@ViewChildren("mytmpl", {read: TemplateRef}) myTemplateList:TemplateRef<any>;
```

2) If you use `ViewChildren`, not `ViewChild`, it returns a collection so you need to access the member by the index:

```
myTemplateList.first
```

So it becomes:

```
@ViewChildren("mytmpl", {read: TemplateRef}) myTemplateList:TemplateRef<any>;
...
let view = this.myTemplateList.first.createEmbeddedView(null)
```

Or simply use `ViewChild`:

```
@ViewChild("mytmpl", {read: TemplateRef}) myTemplateList:TemplateRef<any>;
...
let view = this.myTemplateList.createEmbeddedView(null)
```

> 1) elementRef is undefined!- I want to **print on the console, all the
>   elements inside the template**. but elementRef is undefined!

You can't directly access the elements from the `templateRef`. You need to follow the same process using `@ViewChildren`. The `elementRef` that is available on the `templateRef` as shown [here](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/TemplateRef-class.html) just points to the DOM host element that Angular created for the template element - it's a comment node. It's not what you think it is, not the contents of the template. To get it just use:

```
this.myTemplateList.first.elementRef
```

Read [Exploring Angular DOM manipulation techniques using ViewContainerRef](https://hackernoon.com/exploring-angular-dom-abstractions-80b3ebcfc02) for more details.

Comment: Thanks. That is the tutorial I am following. I added debug print for myTemplateList. It seems it is undefined and thus everything else is undefined. Latest code - `@ViewChildren("mytmpl",{read:TemplateRef}) myTemplateList:TemplateRef<any>; ... ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.myTemplateList);
    let elementRef = this.myTemplateList[0].elementRef
    let view:EmbeddedViewRef<any> = this.myTemplateList[0].createEmbeddedView(null)
    this.v.insert(view)
    console.log(elementRef);
  }`

Comment: can you create a plunker?

Comment: First time using Plunker. Hope the link works - 

https://plnkr.co/edit/lCXzCB5G0NzGxv7nltFc?p=info

Comment: sorry, but your plunker is not doing anything, please make a working plunker which logs `undefined` as you say. the code I showed will work 100%, if it doesn't, then something is wrong with your setup

Comment: sorry about that. Will crack on it in evening.

Comment: can you please check this - https://plnkr.co/edit/Lb24Zp6ycPAcZB2gUWCv The plunker should work but you'll not see anything because the code is defective. If you comment/remove `ng-container` and `ng-template`, you should see the form. I do not know where to look for Console prints in plunker. On browser, I go to developer tools to see the print

Comment: it's working [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/TvK2DLU8MKULoJQry3ff?p=preview). Just use `.first` instead of `[0]` on `myTemplateList`. Also, I told you that there's no `elementRef` in the `templateRef`.

Comment: Thanks. But this link says that elementRef is in templateRef  - https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/TemplateRef-class.html

Comment: @ManuChadha, ah, I see now what your reference to. The `elementRef` that is available on the `templateRef` just points to the DOM host element that Angular created for the template element - it's a comment node. It's not the contents of the template. To get it just use `this.myTemplateList.first.elementRef`

Comment: In your plunker, I think the myTemplateList should be defined as QueryList, not TemplateRef. `first` is defined in QueryList.

Comment: @ManuChadha, it's mine, it's yours :). I just modified it a bit. For the actual runtime behavior the type is not important, but for the compile time type yes, you're right, the type should be `QueryList`.

Comment: Thanks. I went back to my IDE and noticed that the code isn't compiling