# angular templateRef nativeElement is an empty comment instead of original element

Tags: angular, angular5, directive, elementref

I am developing an angular directive that converts dropdownlist to radioListbox.
here is my initial code :

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef,OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[radioList]'
})
export class RadioListDirective implements OnInit  {



  constructor(private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>, private vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    console.log(this.templateRef);
    this.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);

  }
}
```

and

```
<div>
  test
</div>


<select *radioList><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
```

It should log the `TemplateRef` whose `ElementRef` 's nativeElement is a `select`. But the result is and empty comment that its next element is the `select` .

[image]

Comment: Try private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>

Comment: I tried before. Still wont work.

Comment: `It should log the TemplateRef whose ElementRef 's nativeElement is a select` where did you read that? It works as intended

Comment: @yurzui where do you read that this is the intended behavior (referencing an empty comment )?

Comment: `The elementRef that is available on the templateRef as shown here just points to the DOM host element that Angular created for the template element - it's a comment node. ` https://stackoverflow.com/a/44940608/5485167

Answer (score 5):

Hacky solutions currently working:

### Grab the next sibling:

```
this.templateRef.elementRef.nativeElement.nextSibling
```

### Use viewContainerRef.get

```
(this.viewContainerRef.get(0) as any).rootNodes[0]
```

(Note, from your example code you used `vcRef` instead of `viewContainerRef` as I used here.)

Answer (score 0):

Find answered in [Empty native element with ng-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53410210/empty-native-element-with-ng-template)

The ElementRef 's `nativeElement` has nothing to do with the `radioList`, and it is to be a comment element:

```
<!---->
```

This is a preserved feature that, if you binding directive paramater as a input, such that

```
<select *radioList="true"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>
```

Then the directive can have:

```
@Input('radioList') isEnabled: boolean;
```

And the rendered ElementRef 's `nativeElement` becomes:

```
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-is-enabled": "true"
}-->
```

So in conclusion, it is expected.

To continue your code, the `createEmbeddedView` creates a container for everything to be implemented by the `vcRef`, so you can inject cfResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver to resolve e.g. another template component:

```
const cmpFactory = this.cfResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SomeOtherComponent);
this.vcRef.createComponent(cmpFactory);
```