# Empty native element with ng-template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use Angular 5.

In my `component` I have:

```
@ContentChild('contentTemplate') contentTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

my html:

```
<data-grid-column>
  <ng-template #contentTemplate>
    <span class="elo">Hello</span>
  </ng-template>
</data-grid-column>
```

and I am trying to view:

```
ngAfterViewChecked () {
  console.log(this.contentTemplate.elementRef.nativeElement);
}
```

But output is:

```
<!---->
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Are u using a component/directive with a child component/directive?

Comment: I know little Angular. How can I fix this?

Comment: @KamilKamil please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53410403/5043867

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **ng-template** - Is an Angular element for rendering HTML. It is never displayed directly. In fact, before rendering the view, Angular replaces the  and its contents with a comment

As per the official documentation.

Ref.

- https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#the-ng-template

I don't know why you are using `ng-template` here, but you can use `ng-container` instead this will print your content.

Also as you are using `#` local variable on HTML element you need to use `ViewChild` instead, like this -

```
@ViewChild('contentTemplate') contentTemplate: any;
```

## [Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubximv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: this.contentTemplate is undefined :(

Comment: @KamilKamil No, it's working, check in my example given

Comment: Yes but In my case doesnt work.

In my global component I call data-grid-column component, you are doing all in the one component - maybe thats the point? I dont know : ( I tried yesterday similar version and it worked, but i dont remember

Comment: you have <span #contentTemplate in html of your component - I have in another component inside <data-grid-column> - it means, this must to be ContentChild not View - now it will be work.

Comment: No this should not be the reason behind this culprit problem, you can have anything here instead of span. I am just taking example using span.

Comment: Your answer work - if I changed viewchild to childview. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I hope it will work.

```
<ng-container #contentTemplate><span class="elo">Hello</span></ng-container>
```

Comment: it didnt help :(